# How to enable tungsten sort shuffle in Spark 2.1?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

In previous versions, there is a configuration called *spark.shuffle.manage* which is used to determine the type of shuffle algorithm in Spark. Since Spark 2.0, this configuration is deleted. The default shuffle algorithm is the sort-based. As my understanding, the Tungsten shuffle will be enabled only if all the requirements are satisfied. How can I know whether the current job uses the original sort-based shuffle or Tungsten sort?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SortShuffleManager is the one and only ShuffleManager in Apache Spark.

In other words, there's no way you could use any other ShuffleManager but SortShuffleManager (unless you enabled one using `spark.shuffle.manager` property).

Comment: Wow, you are the author of Mastering Spark! The notes help me a lot! I am so exited that you can reply me. Thank you every much. So, currently there is only one shuffle manager. I read [this article](https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/). It introduces 3 algorithms, hash, sort, and tungsten. Hash is removed already. How can I know which shuffle algorithm is applied now (if it is sort or tungsten sort). I am a little confused. Tungsten has some conditions have to hold as mentioned in that article. If those conditions don't hold, will the original sort algorithm be applied?

Comment: Things have since changed and the article (although a very good one at that time) is not obsolete. See the code yourself.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, regarding this question, just curious why hash shuffle manager was removed in spark 2.x.? Thanks